# I'm not able to delete elements of these vectors

Tags: c++, oop, templates, segmentation-fault, virtual

I want to delete every element at a certain index (that corresponds to a certain content), but I'm getting a segmentation fault... This is the structure of my code and the method `deleteRecord` is what I've tried but doesn't work:

```
class Tab {

public:
    Tab();
    ~Tab() {};
    bool colIsPresent(const string & col_name);
    template <typename S> void deleteRecord(S & content, const string & col_name) {
        int delete_pos;
        if (!this->colIsPresent(col_name)) return;
        const auto & it_columns = _columns.find(col_name);
        if (it_columns != _columns.end()) {
            auto ci = dynamic_cast<ColumnImpl<S> *>(it_columns->second.get());
            if (ci != nullptr) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ci->getData().size(); i++) {
                    if (ci->getData()[i] == content) {
                        delete_pos = i;
                    }
                    for (auto & it_columns_2 : _columns) {
                        auto ci2 = dynamic_cast<ColumnImpl<S> *>(it_columns_2.second.get());
                        ci2->getData().erase(ci2->getData().begin() + delete_pos);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
private:
    map<string, shared_ptr<Column>> _columns;
};
```

```
template <typename T> class ColumnImpl : public Column {
public:
    ColumnImpl() : Column() {}
    ColumnImpl(const T& to_set);
    vector<T> & getData() { return _data; }
protected:
    vector<T> _data;
};
```

```
class Column {
public:
    Column();
    virtual ~Column() {};
    virtual string getType() = 0;
};
```

```
class Database {
public:
    Database();
    ~Database();
    bool tabIsPresent(const string & tab_name);
    template <typename S> void deleteRecordFromTab(const string & tab_name, S & content, const string & col_name) {
        const auto & it_target_tab = _tables.find(tab_name);
        it_target_tab->second.deleteRecord(content, col_name);
    }

private:
    map<string, Tab> _tables;
};
```

Reproducible example:

```
    Database data_base;
    string tab = "EX_TAB", str1 = "STR_EX1", str2 = "STR_EX2", age = "AGE", name = "NAME", integer = "INT", text = "TEXT";
    int a = 17, b = 18;
    data_base.createNewTable(tab);
    data_base.addColumnToTab(tab, age, integer);
    data_base.addColumnToTab(tab, name, text);
    data_base.addElemToColOfTab(tab, age, a);
    data_base.addElemToColOfTab(tab, age, b);
    data_base.addElemToColOfTab(tab, name, str1);
    data_base.addElemToColOfTab(tab, name, str2);
    data_base.deleteRecordFromTab(tab, str1, name);

    // createNewTable creates a new table
    // addColumnToTab adds a new column of the right type to _columns
    // addElemToColumnOfTab adds an element to the targeted column
```

Comment: What exactly is the criteria for deletion?  Have you tried the [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) idiom?

Comment: One problem is that `ci->getData().size()` could change inside the loop, but you don't account for it.

Comment: I have many different `Column`s with many `_data` vectors. I want to find the index at which I have a certain value and delete every element of every vector at that index...

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Should I save the initial value into a variable?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Could you tell me what other parts would be useful? Should I show how I want to use the method?

Comment: @JohnBardeen -- *I have many different Columns with many _data vectors. I want to find the index at which I have a certain value and delete every element of every vector at that index...* -- So basically you have `n` vectors, and at index `i`, you want to delete item `i` from all the vectors.  If that's so, then you could have put together a much easier example than one with `maps`, `shared_ptr`, etc.

Comment: You're potentially using `delete_pos` before it has been initialized.

Comment: The "parts" that "would be useful" are, like I explained, an example that can be cut/pasted, ***exactly as shown***, and reproduce your problem. Can you answer the following question: can you take ***exactly*** what's shown in the question, cut/paste it, compile it, run it, and reproduce your crash? Unless you can answer "yes", this is not a [mre].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've put the "real" code because I think I'm messing up with these difficult (for me) objects

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you, I'm going to check right now

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok I'm sorry, I'm going to edit my question

Comment: @JohnBardeen -- So conceptually, how is what you described any different than [this simple example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c30ea60301da2f45)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's not different, but the fact is that I've just learnt of dynamic_cast and I highly suspect I'm not using it in a correct way

Comment: dynamic_cast can throw an exception - I would make sure that your code will catch such an exception. I strongly suspect the problem is you are deleting from a vector whilst looping over it. Following link is an example of the erase remove idiom: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: Thank you @castro I'll read it. Anyway I've edited my question, because the method doesn't work only if I use it with the `Database`'s class method...

Comment: You check `ci != nullptr`, but you don't check `ci2` but just blindly use it. If not all columns are of the same type `S`, `dynamic_cast<ColumnImpl<S> *>(it_columns_2.second.get())` would return `nullptr` for some of them, and then your program would exhibit undefined behavior by way of dereferencing a null pointer. One way around it would be to give `Column` a pure virtual `DeleteAtPos` method, and have  `ColumnImpl` implement it. Then you won't need to `dynamic_cast` for `erase`.

Comment: You are running the `erase` loop even when `ci->getData()[i]` does not in fact equal `content` - sometimes with uninitialized `delete_pos`, other times with stale value of `delete_pos` left over from previous iteration.

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik that's what I'm going to do then!